# Definition of vectors

Tags: vectors, definition, mathematics, geometry

I know that we call a quantity a vector if it has magnitude and direction and follows vector laws of addition(the triangle law and parallelogram law). But why only it should only follow addition laws and not other laws like cross product or dot product and why they are not given in its definition.
Is it like that if a quantity follows vector laws of addition it also surely follows laws of cross product or dot product or etc.

Comment: The study of vector algebra is best suited for [Math.SE] and not [Physics.SE]. Also note that not all vectors have cross-products defined.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/62318/3301

Comment: The accepted answer to the link above answers your question.

Comment: The definition of a vector is not independent of the definition of a *vector space*, which includes quite a few more axioms than vector addition..

Comment: The cross product only exists in three and (in somewhat modified form) in seven dimensions. If you want to talk about general algebraic properties of geometry, then you need to study more general objects like tensors.

Comment: Physicists have a slightly different idea of what a vector is than mathematicians. This has been discussed more than once on this site, as have related objects. For example [Visualizing Tensors in the simplest possible way](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/673050/37364) or [Why do we need a unit vector?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/748063/37364)

Answer (score 2):

In mathematical physics, many vector spaces are used and some are not "geometric" spaces.

For example, when we solve a linear differential equation of order 2, we know that the space of solutions is a vector space of dimension 2. A basis, of dimension 2, is formed by two linearly independent functions and the general solution is a linear combination of these two functions. You only need the concepts of the sum of two functions and the product of a function by a real. At this level, there is no vector product and even the definition of a scalar product is not essential: at an elementary level, we are not talking about the norm of a function when solving a differential equation. (even if it is useful to go further).